# Unable to Connect to a Remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, firewall, vps

I can connect to a remote sql server at home but not in the office. The server where the SQL Server is hosted is a VPS (Arvixe). How can I check if a firewall is making me not able to connect on that server?

Comment: Ask your SysAdmin in the office. :-)

Comment: The first clue it might be a firewall will be the inability to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact the hosting company. If you set the VPS up from home and did not add your office as a connection site then there definitely should be a firewall blocking you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a firewall, then you will either get a "connection timed out" or "connection refused". Otherwise, the SQL error will say why you can't connect. Usually it's because the user has a restrictive host list and your office IP isn't on the list so it tosses a login failure.